# Issue with FindControl on the second page of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatables, findcontrol

I'm using Gridview + Datatables js for paging.

I would like to loop through the gridview rows in the back end, but it seems like I can't use row.FindCountrol method to find a HiddenField control on the rows that are currently not displayed (i.e. not on the current page).

Am I missing something?

Update: The code is really simple, on the button event I iterate through the collection of gridview rows:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdClientShaping.Rows)
    {
        string s = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hdnImmediateParentID")).Value;
    }
```

I know that every single row has this control with value populated, but the above returns values only for rows that are displayed on the current gridview page.

Comment: post the code of how do you call row.findControl and when do you call it, also, which is exactly the library are you using?

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta Please see the update. I use http://datatables.net/ jquery library for paging

Comment: My guess is that this jquery plugin is changing the html structure of the table generated by the asp.net, so when you post back there are only X amount of rows actualy in the form. You can inpect the html using firebug and see if that is the case

Comment: @jekcom thanks for the reply. I assumed so, but I can definitely see all rows in the collection and it's only the HiddenField that does not get found, i.e. I can find labels and textboxes. And when I check the HTML, it's there.

Comment: Where is hdnImmediateParentID located at? Could you post GridView markup inside aspx page?

Comment: Did you check if it works correctly without the jquery plugin?

Comment: I replaced the HiddenField with a Label control (made it invisible) and it all started working.